# Most efficient and reliable way to get Unix files into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, unix, batch-file, cross-platform

I've got three files on AIX that I need to import into a SQL Server 2005 database. The files are created by an AIX script that I have control over. There are several options that I know will work, but I'd like to find out what others have done before and what works best.

Here are the options I'm looking at.

1. Have the AIX script sftp the files to Windows and then have a Windows batch job bcp them into SQL Server.
2. Same thing except have the Windows batch job GET the files instead of having the AIX script PUT them.
3. Same as #1 except use scp instead of sftp (what are the pros & cons?)
4. Set up a samba share on AIX and have the Windows batch job bcp the files into SQL Server from there
5. Same as #4 except use SSIS to import them as flat files from the samba share (not sure how this will work with line endings).

Are there other good options I'm overlooking? Does any of these stand out as better for some objective reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My recommendation would be SSIS, it gives you greater control over the parsing and reading of the controls before insert.

Comment: Thanks for the post. Is this something you've actually done before (pointing SSIS to a samba share)? I'm interested to see what pitfalls there may be.

Comment: Yes SSIS is very good at picking up things from network shares.  I haven't had a problem yet.  If you have some custom format text, you may have to make a custom processing node in a .NET language, but those are very easy to create too.  I highly recommend SSIS over any of your other methods.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend SSIS. It allows you to design the entire data flow including the FTP get operation, application of transformations and mapping of the file to a table.

You can then have the SSIS package even run on a schedule using the SQL Server Agent if needed.

**EDIT:** You can **[define variables](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/passing-variables-to-and-from-an-ssis-task/)** inside the SSIS package, which you can then pass on through the Agent job. This can include your FTP path and credentials.

[alt text http://www.webholstad.com/clarity/blogpics/ssissetvar.jpg](http://www.webholstad.com/clarity/blogpics/ssissetvar.jpg)

Comment: This is a good suggestion. I didn't know you could FTP from within SSIS. I'm trying to avoid storing any credentials in SSIS (because we have a pretty strict expiration policy). Do you know if it's possible to configure SSIS to FTP without storing the credentials in the package?